# How to pass values directly from THEME_NAME.info to THEME_form_system_theme_settings_submit()

Tags: 7, forms

Does anyone know a smarter way to load given settings from the THEMENAME.info file for the submit function only, than to create another "ghost"-form calling theme_get_setting() ? I would like to prevent the ghost form, since there is no input needed.

I only need some settings from the info file in the submit state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a form to save these values. 
[`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) and [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) functions will make it much easier to set the value and retrieve it.

However, if you still want to pass the information via the theme's .info file, you can do as follows:

**Add your custom variables to the .info file**

EX:
my_awesome_theme.info file:

```
name = my_awesome_theme
core = 7.x
dragons_exists = 1
how_to_catch_a_dragon[] = "Be a dragonlord"
how_to_catch_a_dragon[] = "Tell him to surrender"
```

Drupal will ignore these extra stuff during normal module/theme scanning.

**To get the value, you can it like this:**

```
$data = drupal_parse_info_file('sites/all/themes/my_awesome_theme.info');
```

You can use functions like [`drupal_get_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) to get the correct path. 
`$data` will contain the values from the .info file. 
For example,  the above .info file will yield

[image: dpm() of the .info array]

Note that [`drupal_parse_info_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_parse_info_file/7) doc mentions that you should NOT use this method to store arbitrary data.

> Parses Drupal module and theme .info files.
>
> Info files are NOT for placing arbitrary theme and module-specific
>   settings. Use variable_get() and variable_set() for that.

**Update:**
If you only need to pass some variable **from the form**, and not necessarily from the .info file, just store the value in `$form_state`. 
As long as you don't overwrite some existing values, `$form_state['values']` for example, it will work just fine.

Also, consider using a form element of [`#type => value`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#val). User will not see anything at all, not even a hidden form element. You can access this value from `$form_state['values']` nevertheless.

Comment: wow! awesome. clear and understandable but with all needed info packed to get the whole picture. Awesome answer! Thank you very much [Ayesh K](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1899/ayesh-k)!

Comment: one drawback on both methods is that it causes many heat to get one,two values. I like your very detailed answer but I will stay with a small hidden form, which will load the only 1,2 values I need via default_value => theme_get_setting, since Drupal will look at info file if values does not exist in database. Then, I can pick up the values via $form_state['info'] on the submit level.

Comment: Thanks @Nils. Please see the updated answer with some suggestions to pass values *from the form*.

Comment: Thanks Ayesh K. perfect. This is how we can leave the answer. Now it is up to the use case. Thank you very much.